# Cannot receive Image over TCP socket?

Tags: c#, image, tcp, client-server, networkstream

I have problem with receiving an image over TCP socket  [.net 4.0]

Server:

```
Socket s = null;
Socket client;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9988));
        s.Listen(1);
        client = s.Accept();

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new NetworkStream(client));
        //Server freezes here and waiting for the image .. but in the Client side.. it tells that it sent.

        Console.WriteLine("Received.");
    }
```

Client:

```
Socket s = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9988));
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        bitmap.Save(new NetworkStream(s), ImageFormat.Png);
        Console.WriteLine("sent.");
    }
```

**Edit:**
im making a big application .. image was receiving just fine .. then i did some changes on the code so it got complicated to know what did i exactly change .. now it's not working .. so i made new projects and tried the code up.. still doesn't work .. i know that there's another ways to do it.. but i prefer to do this way.
Anyone knows how to fix it ??

Comment: maybe you begin, by describing where exactly your problem is....

Comment: @CarstenKönig at that comment in server code .. the server doesn't receive it blocked at the pictureBox line .. can you read it!

Comment: Does the server pictureBox1 control or class understand that it is expecting a png formatted byte-stream? It might not be finishing because there might be metadata in the png format which indicates the size of the image and if the receiving end doesn't know this it won't know when it has received all the data?

Comment: It looks like Image.FromStream will automatically detect the format for you so that's probably not your problem.

Comment: @ShaneWealti yea it was working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you need to close the socket after sending the data.

`Image.FromStream()` probably waits until the `NetworkStream` indicates there are no more bytes to process, but since you declared the `Socket` on the form's class level, it stays connected and the server waits for more data.

Comment: Finally .. that's why it stopped working after i modify my code.. !! but i need that connection .. is there anyway to keep it alive?

Comment: You can keep it alive - but then you'd need some mechanism of telling the server that the first image was sent, and that the next received byte belongs to a new one. This means you'll have to send additional data (for instance, first send the image size, followed by image data) and at the server side you'll need to parse and split the data.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to convert the image to byte and then get the byte's size and send it to the server, the server prepares the buffer size and then the client send the image's bytes, you can find s video on how to do it  [Right Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mYoJBT9XIg&feature=channel&list=UL)